# Function that parses CSS styles string into JS inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress, string, parsing

I need to create a function that parses a CSS string, that will be used on a inline js style.

E.g: what I get is something like `const styles = "background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000"` and I need to transform in:

```
      <h1
        className={classes}
        style={{ color: fontColor, background: backgroundColor }}
      >
        {copy}
      </h1>
```

what I do for now is this

```
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState();
  const [fontColor, setFontColor] = useState();
  const colors = styles?.match(/(#)([^;]*)/g);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (colors) {
      if (colors.length > 1) {
        setBackgroundColor(colors[0]);
        setFontColor(colors[1]);
      }

      if (colors.length === 1) {
        setFontColor(colors[0]);
      }
    }
  }, [colors]);
```

But I was asked to create pure seperate function that parses the styles string.

So I was wondering if there's a solution where I don't need to "regex" each **specific** selector and then its value. If there's something like whatever is before the colon is the selector than after that until the semicolon is its value.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: yes its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this and after that map your function with it

```js
const styles = "background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000";

const css = styles.split(';').map(cur => cur.split(':'));

console.log(css);

const cssInObject = styles.split(';').map(cur => cur.split(':')).reduce((acc, val) => {
    let [key, value] = val;
    key = key.replace(/-./g, css => css.toUpperCase()[1])
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(cssInObject);
```

Comment: I added react way of css, look out

Comment: your solution works also on Safari!.. Great! Thanks! :)

Comment: I glad you like my answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (which converts the css string to an object) **(doesn't work on Safari)**:

```
const convertCssToObject = value => {
    
  const regex = /(?<=^|;)\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+)\s*/g, o = {};
  value.replace(regex, (m,p,v) => o[p] = v);
  return o;
    
}

console.log( convertCssToObject("background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;") )
```

I've edited the regex so it works also on Safari:

```
const convertCssToObject = value => {
  // Without the look behind
  const regex = /([\w-.]+)\s*:([^;]+);?/g, o = {}; // Heck I think this should also work for Chrome as well
  value.replace(regex, (m,p,v) => o[p] = v);
  return o;
}

console.log( convertCssToObject("background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;") )
```

Comment: unfortunately, I was just flagged that your solution does not work on Safari.
I really liked cause it is very concise, but in the end, I won't be able to use it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ah I guess Safari doesn't like to "look back". I'll update my comment